# Magento 2 REST API: Get list and details of all active coupons

Tags: magento2, rest-api, coupon-codes

Is there an API to get the list of all active coupon codes from magento 2?

> /V1/coupons/search

this shows me all the coupons, but it doesn't give any information about if the coupon is active or it's description.

and

> /V1/salesRules/search

This gives the details but not the coupon code.

Is there any way to get all details in a single api call?

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your clarification, the coupon code in magento Don't have a separate **"Active"** Status and Description.

The **Active Status** and **Description** belongs to the **SalesRules/CartPriceRule** entity.

By Default there is no single api call which fetches all your details, but however you can implement a custom api for your needs.